# ChildbyAuto ID creating new child reference

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm only a month into learning Swift and programming in general. So please bear with be.

I'm trying to change a child value inside a Child created by ChildbyAutoID. The value i want to change is the isChecked Value. But all it does it create a new Child and set's the value inside there.

My View Controller

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class guestListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var guestListTableView: UITableView!



var guestListDBRef : DatabaseReference!
var guestListText = [AdminTextModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guestListDBRef = Database.database().reference().child("RSVP")
    guestListDBRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
        for guestListLabel in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let guestListTextObject = guestListLabel.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let name = guestListTextObject?["name"]
            let date = guestListTextObject?["date"]
            let isChecked = guestListTextObject?["isChecked"]
            let key = guestListTextObject?["keyID"]
            let guestListTextLabels = AdminTextModel(key: key as! String?, name: name as! String?, date: date as! String?, isChecked: isChecked as! Bool? )
            self.guestListText.append(guestListTextLabels)
            self.guestListTableView.rowHeight = 45
            self.guestListTableView.reloadData()


            }
        }
    })

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return guestListText.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let GuestListTextCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestList") as! GuestListTableViewCell
    let text: AdminTextModel
    text = guestListText[indexPath.row]

    GuestListTextCell.guestListNameLabel.text = text.name
    GuestListTextCell.guestListDateLabel.text = text.date

    if text.isChecked! {
        GuestListTextCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }else {
        GuestListTextCell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return GuestListTextCell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let isChecked = self.guestListText[indexPath.row].isChecked!
    self.guestListText[indexPath.row].isChecked! = true
    let key = self.guestListText[indexPath.row].key



    Checkedservice.checkuncheck(key: key!, isChecked: isChecked) { (seccess) in
        guard seccess else { return }
        self.guestListText[indexPath.row].isChecked = true

        self.guestListTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        print("\(isChecked)")
        print(key!)
    }
}

struct Checkedservice {
    static func checkuncheck(key: String, isChecked: Bool, success: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        let onlinesRef = Database.database().reference().child("RSVP").child(key).child("isChecked")
        onlinesRef.setValue(isChecked) {(error, _ ) in

            if let error = error {
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
                success(false)
            }
            success(true)
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

My Custom Text Model
    import Foundation

```
class AdminTextModel {
var key: String?
var name: String?
var date: String?
var isChecked: Bool?
init(key: String?, name: String?, date: String?, isChecked: Bool?) {
    self.key = key
    self.name = name
    self.date = date
    self.isChecked = isChecked

    }
}
```

My TableViewCell Class

```
import UIKit

class GuestListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var guestListDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var guestListNameLabel: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and this is how I am writing to my Database.

```
@IBAction func rsvpButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let key = rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").childByAutoId().key
    let guestList = [
        "keyID": key,
        "name": nameTextField.text!,
        "date": dateTextField.text!,
        "isChecked": false] as [String : Any]
   rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").childByAutoId().setValue(guestList)
    if (nameTextField.text == nil) || dateTextField.text == nil {
        print("No RSVP Entered")
        self.dateTextField.text = nil
        self.nameTextField.text = nil
    }
    dateTextField.text = ""
    nameTextField.text = ""
}
```

My end goal is to check and uncheck cells. But when i reload the view, the check and unchecked cells are still there. Thank You so much!

My firebase structure

[image: My Firebase Structure]

Comment: Ever time you call `childByAutoId()`, Firebase generates a new location. To update an existing RSVP you will need to know its ID. Is the `key` you're passing into `checkuncheck` indeed the ID of the item you want to update?

Comment: @ Frank Added Photo

Comment: It seems that you're calling `childByAutoId()` twice there, given that there are two child nodes. Btw: You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AdrianNavarro In general its like copy and paste if you paste at same path it will replace else it will create new one. I found one mistake in `rsvpButton` action at `let key = rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").childByAutoId().key` line. You should create a ref then get the key else it will give you different key. So this should be `let ref = rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").childByAutoId()` and `let key = ref.key` then use this `ref` and `key`. Everytime you write`rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").childByAutoId()` will create a new reference and key.

Answer (score 0):

I think You have confused "How to add or update the record in firebase". Let understand when we will use `childByAutoId(). As per firebase documentation.

> childByAutoId generates a new child location using a unique key and
>   returns a Firebase reference to it. This is useful when the children
>   of a Firebase database location represent a list of items.

That means it will create new items every time with unique key value once you have executed `childByAutoId()` with the specific reference.

**Solution:**

I suggest please use below line of code to update or add value.

**Update:**

You can also do it as below.

```
  let key = rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").childByAutoId().key

  rsvpRef.child("key").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild(key){
            print("exist")
            let guestList = [
            "keyID": key,
            "name": nameTextField.text!,
            "date": dateTextField.text!,
            "isChecked": false] as [String : Any]

            rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").updateChildValues(guestList)
        }else{
            print("doesn't exist")
            rsvpRef?.child("RSVP").childByAutoId().setValue(guestList)
        }
    })
```

Comment: I’m just a little confused on where to add this code. I’m sorry.

Comment: i'm having trouble understanding the "room1" string

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func rsvpButton(_ sender: Any)
{
   // Get first ID of your record 

   let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "RSVP").observe(.childAdded)
       { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

       // Here you will get your ID now Update value
          print(snapshot.key)

       //here is your value
       let guestList = [
                    "keyID": key,
                    "name": nameTextField.text!,
                    "date": dateTextField.text!,
                    "isChecked": false] as [String : Any]

       // Update your Child Valus
          Database.database().reference(withPath: "RSVP").child(snapshot.key).updateChildValues(guestList)
      }

}
```